# Java HTTP GET request gives 403 Forbidden, but works in browser

Tags: java, http, get

I have some code, which is meant to send a GET request via HTTP to a server, and fetch the data there. I haven't yet coded the part that does stuff with the response, as I first wanted to test whether the GET request worked. And it didn't:

```
private static String fetch() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        // Set the parameters
        String url = "http://www.futhead.com";
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        //Fire the request
        try {
        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
        // ^^^ I tried this, and it doesn't help!
        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        System.out.println("Status: " + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // stuff
        }
        return null;
        // ^^^ I haven't coded the fetching itself yet
    }
```

With that code in mind, `fetch()` prints `Status: 403`. Why is this happening? My guess is that this particular server doesn't let non-browser clients access it (because the code works with `http://www.google.com`), but is there a workaround?

There are some answers out there already, but some of them are either irrelevant to me (they talk about a problem with HTTPS) or incomprehensible. I've tried those that I can understand, to no avail.

Comment: Use Wireshark and compare the request your browser does and your coded request. The server propably throws 403 because of a particular header line use are missing/is different.

Comment: Right. Do I look at the headers my browser sends, and replicate all of them in my GET?

Comment: I looked at the cookies the website sets, and it appears that it uses CloudFlare, which sets a `__cfduid` cookie. You might have to [handle this cookie](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html).

Comment: I'll try that. But, out of interest, why do I need to handle a cookie to avoid a 403?

Answer (score 3):

You might have Browser Integrity Check enabled https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-What-does-the-Browser-Integrity-Check-do-

I disabled Browser Integrity Check and it works fine now. Another solution would be to set User-Agent, if possible.

I experienced the problem from Scala, which eventually uses java.net.URL